# Python Pandas Filter By Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that I have a Pandas dataframe with seven columns set up as following:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  8  9  0  1  2  3  4`
```

Now I would like to create a new dataframe in which all columns from `A` to `E` to be filtered from range `x` to `y` (inclusive of `x` and `y`) and column `F` to be filtered between value `x` and `z` (inclusive of `x` and `z`).

What would be the best approach to this issue?

Much Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of filter do you want to use?

Comment: kindly include values for x,y,z with expected output

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
df[cols] = df[cols].where(df[cols].le(y) & df[cols].ge(x))
df['F'] = df['F'].where(df['F'].between(x, z, inclusive=True))
```